# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Добрый день, очень нужно сделать синтаксический разбор предложения. Помогите, пожалуйста.

"Рассматривая народ как существо духовного порядка, мы можем назвать язык, на котором он говорит, его душой, и тогда история этого языка будет значительнее, чем даже история политических изменений этого народа с которыми, однако, история его тесно связан. "

Comment: "история его тесно связан" --- (1) Пропущена буква "а" (правильно: связана) (2) слово "его" расположено так, как будто относится к народу, а на деле оно должно относиться к языку (история языка тесно связана с политическими изменениями). "Политические изменения народа" - довольно коряво, я бы сказал: "политические изменения в жизни народа"

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном предложении есть ошибки, поэтому пишу его с исправлениями:
"Рассматривая народ как существо духовного порядка, мы можем назвать язык, на котором он говорит, его душой, и тогда история этого языка будет значительнее, чем даже история политических изменений этого народа, с которыми, однако, история его тесно связана." Что касается синтаксической характеристики этого предложения, то это сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью